# APA 7th edition. Page number of direct quote vs referenced in-text citation

Tags: thesis, writing

I'm stating a direct quote using APA 7th edition standards that is re-quoted by other authors.  I have a page number for the quoted statement, but then I have the referenced in-text citations that have the quote elsewhere.

**Hyun et al. (2020) addressed this by stating, “to achieve organizational agility, companies must implement both high-speed and high-quality decision-making” (p. 39) (Ghasemaghaei et al., 2018; Westerman, 2009; Samsudin & Ismail, 2019).**

Do I have the format correct?  I'm not sure, as I can't find the relevant guidance for this.
Thanks!

Comment: I tried to answer your question but then got confused. Could you highlight *precisely* the entire part of the source that you are using. Does your source, for example, say "Hyun .... (p. 39)" or does it include the author list at the end ... and does it exclude the words "Hyun ..." and simply run fro "to achieve" to "p. 39)"?? Or does it omit that page number. Separating what you are writing from the exact text of your source would be helpful.

Comment: so the quote is what I need and it's on page 39 in Hyun's document...but the quote is also referenced by three other papers.  I was trying to show all the referencing going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the original source of your quotation and worked from there. The source is Hyun et al. (as you mention) and can be accessed through [here](https://aisel.aisnet.org/pajais/vol12/iss2/2/). The words that appear in Hyun et al. are

> To achieve organizational agility, companies must implement both high-speed and high-quality decision making (Ghasemaghaei et al., 2018; Westerman, 2009; Samsudin & Ismail, 2019).

I think that most people would shorten this simply by writing:

> Hyun et al. (2020) addressed this by stating, “to achieve organizational agility, companies must implement both high-speed and high-quality decision-making” (p. 39)

... but if you ***really*** want to quote the extra referencing at the end of the sentence, then you should treat it according section 8.32 of the Publication Manual as mentioned on [this APA page](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/quotations), and write:

> Hyun et al. (2020) addressed this by stating, “to achieve organizational agility, companies must implement both high-speed and high-quality decision-making  (Ghasemaghaei et al., 2018; Westerman, 2009; Samsudin & Ismail, 2019)” (p. 39)

Note that the quotation marks surround the entirety of the quoted material including the quoted in-line referencing, and that the page number on which the quoted material appears is situated at the end of the entire quote.

Do not include any of the following: *Ghasemaghaei et al., 2018; Westerman, 2009; Samsudin & Ismail, 2019* in your own reference list, whether or not you include them in the block quote To do so would be to suggest that you had read them.

Comment: Thank you so much for this

Comment: This helps alot

Comment: Apa is somewhat complicated when learning

Comment: APA is  indeed complicated but the actual specification is one of the clearest of any style-guide that I know of, despite its complexity. If you can find a copy of a 5th edition (NOT the latest) APA Publication Guide, you will find that it has a lot of material omitted from the 6th and 7th editions despite the material still being current. It's worth looking for a 2nd hand copy.